# How do I achieve the “mouth sealing effect” from The Matrix in Blender?

Tags: animation, mesh, objects, particles

I get that this moment itself was scary when I was a kid.
[image: From The Matrix 1999]

But honestly, I want to ask. How is this possible? Also, when I saw the red pill teaser for the new Matrix movie, Jonathan Groff’s character’s mouth sealed itself shut the same way like Neo’s in the first film.
[image: From The Matrix Resurrections]

The reason is, I wanna try it out for myself.

So yeah, I have many questions. How do the strands of the mesh merge in order to disappear? Is it liquid or cloth? Is it faces or thickened edges? More importantly, is it even possible to achieve this effect in Blender?

Whatever it is, I must know. Thank you.

Comment: looks like a stretched bubble gum effect to me https://youtu.be/SZ3VoXciW1g and https://youtu.be/ihW4myc7Fko

Comment: You’re close. But, how did the strands fuse together is what I’m asking.